# Summernote editable area issue

Tags: jquery, summernote

how to separate **Summernote** toolbar from Summernote Editable area using JQuery.
Like **Summernote**  toolbar will be in nav-bar and it's editable area will be below my website header.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this

```
$(".note-toolbar-wrapper").appendTo($("selector-of-new-element"));
```

Comment: I have already appended toolbar to my website nav-bar. I want to separate summernote editable area from toolbar and use it below nav-bar

Comment: @ShahHassan First put the entire summernote below nav-bar and use the code in answer to move the toolbar to nav-bar

Comment: Thank you dear. I tried it, but still **Summernote** toolbar is showing on the footer while I have placed it within "nav-bar"